# Should Rabbitmq consumer be run as service

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a question that on a Linux server for continuous running should Rabbitmq consumer be run as service like a printer service? I don't think keeping a terminal window open all the time is the right method. Please suggest.

Comment: On a server, it should run as a dockerized service. But the gist is—`rabbitmq` is supposed to be run as a long-running service.

Comment: Thanks Redowen. I understand but I hope we are talking about the same thing. I am asking about the consumer program which runs in an infinite loop to wait for the new messages on the queue.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood it. Yes, you can either keep the terminal running and it's usually fine. However, if the number of terminals goes out of hand then you can write a bash script that will spin up and clean up everything for you. There is another approach, using docker for that as well and instead of spinning up terminals, you can launch different processes for that.